# Changing buttons into checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

Hello for everyone :) I have a rails app with user and calendar 
I have a js file

```
calEvents = ''

    $(document).on 'click', 'all_user_events', ->
      calEvents = '/events.json'
      return

    $(document).on 'click', 'user_events', ->
      calEvents = '/events/user_events.json'
      return

    $(document).ready ->
      calEvents = '/events.json'
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar(

        events: calEvents
        eventColor: '#378006'
        eventBackgroundColor: 'red'

    )
```

As you see, user can choose which format of fullCalendar he wants by 2 button. I want to change this two buttons in one check box. (if checked than all events,  else  only your events). How should i do this? im new at rails :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
$(document).on 'change', 'check-all-events', ->
  if @checked
    calEvents = 'events.json'
    return
  else
    calEvents = 'events/user_events.json'
    return
```

You can do it as:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'all_events', {}, false, id: "check-all-events"%>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, the last problem in check box. How should i put it in view? with what parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ........

```
$("#checkbox_id").on 'click', ->
  if @checked
    calEvents = 'events.json'
    return
  else
    calEvents = 'events/user_events.json'
    return
```

In your view add checkbox like this.

```
<%= check_box_tag 'events', {}, false, id: "checkbox_id"%>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, the last problem in check box. How should i put it in view? with what parameters? –